# How to record ocsp application using with jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

I need to record ocsp based application in jmeter.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other application, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol)

> Messages communicated via OCSP are encoded in ASN.1 and are usually communicated over HTTP.

so theoretically you can record the network flow using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

However you won't be able to replay it because OCSP requests require some complex calculations. Example code to generate and sign the request:

```
import org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.CertificateID;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.OCSPReq;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.OCSPReqBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.*;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.*;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.*;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.*;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.DigestCalculatorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;


String BC = vars.get('"securityProvider');
String fName = vars.get("certpath");

Reader fR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));
PEMParser pPar = new PEMParser(fR);

X509CertificateHolder obj = (X509CertificateHolder)pPar.readObject();

DigestCalculatorProvider dCP = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(BC).build();

CertificateID cId = new CertificateID(dCP.get(CertificateID.HASH_SHA1), obj, obj.getSerialNumber());

OCSPReqBuilder oRB = new OCSPReqBuilder();
oRB.addRequest(cId);
OCSPReq oReq = oRB.build();

byte[] asn1seq = oReq.getEncoded();

String sb = new String(asn1seq);

sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(sb);
```

check out [How to Test OCSP](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ocsp-test#six) article for more details.